# Reduce and split into several column in R

Tags: r, regex

I have one problem with my Amino_acid mutation data. for example,

```
p.K303R   
p.?
p.R1450*
```

and I want like this outopt

```
AA_mutation wt_residue  position    mt_residue
p.K303R       K          303           R
p.?         
p.R1450*      R           1450         *
```

I want to remove "p.","?" from the data and also split into three new variable. I have managed it on excel but not in R platform. 
Could someone help me please on R.
Kind regards
Fakhrul

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `extract` (have [**some reading here**](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html)), we can use:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(AA_mutation = c("p.K303R", "p.?", "p.R1450*"))
df <- df %>%
  extract(AA_mutation, 
          into = c("wt_residue", "position", "mt_residue"), 
          regex = "p\\.([A-Z])?(\\d+)?([A-Z*])?",
          remove = FALSE)
df
```

Yielding

```
  AA_mutation wt_residue position mt_residue
1     p.K303R          K      303          R
2         p.?       <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
3    p.R1450*          R     1450          *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `base R`

```
lst <- regmatches(df1[[1]], gregexpr("([a-z]+)|([A-Z*]+)|[0-9]+", df1[[1]], perl = TRUE))
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
names(res) <- c("AA_mutation", "wt_residue",  "position",    "mt_residue")
res
#  AA_mutation wt_residue position mt_residue
#1           p          K      303          R
#2           p       <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
#3           p          R     1450          *
```